# Why rsync doesn't include a nested directory?

Tags: rsync

Given the following directory structure:

```
$ cd /home/user/test/
$ mkdir -p source/b/c/
$ touch source/b/c/d.txt
$ tree source/
source/
└── [4.0K]  b
    └── [4.0K]  c
        └── [   0]  d.txt
```

Why this command copies the folders as expected:

```
$ pwd
/home/user/test/
$ rsync -av -n --include="b/***" --exclude="*" source/ target
sending incremental file list
created directory target
./
b/
b/c/
b/c/d.txt

sent 141 bytes  received 59 bytes  400.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

But this doesn't?

```
$ pwd
/home/user/test/
$ rsync -av -n --include="b/c/***" --exclude="*" source/ target
sending incremental file list
./

sent 59 bytes  received 19 bytes  156.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

How I stumbled upon it: I'm trying to synchronise multiple variably-nested directories while preserving overall directory structure.

Why the more-specific include rule fails to match anything?

Comment: Please recheck the commands you posted. In the first one, `tree source/` does not show the directory `a` ... Also note that the ouput will change, depending on where you are standing. To test, I suggest you use full paths, or add the output of `pwd` when you mention the commands' results.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani - My bad, fixed.

Comment: recursive flag is missing `-r` , but why exclude="*" ?!

Comment: @Jonah because there might be a `b/x/unwanted.txt` (for multiple values of `x`), and the OP only wants `b/c/...`

Comment: @Jonah - `-a` implies `-r`. And @roaima is exactly right about the exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First example**

```
rsync -av -n --include="b/***" --exclude="*" source/ target
```

- Include directory `b` and everything underneath it
- Exclude everything (else)

So `b` and its children get backed up

**Second example**

```
rsync -av -n --include="b/c/***" --exclude="*" source/ target
```

- Include directory `b/c` and everything underneath `c`
- Exclude everything (else)

The problem here is that you have not included `b` so `rsync` will never find `b/c`. The solution is to include `b` explicitly,

```
rsync -av -n --include='b/' --include="b/c/***" --exclude="*" source/ target
```

- Include directory `b`
- Include directory `b/c` and everything underneath `c`
- Exclude everything (else)

Comment: So it looks at "b", sees that it matches the `--exclude="*"`, and doesn't recurse inside, correct?

Comment: @Rogach correct